# Where is the mistake $\oint_C \frac{e^\frac{1}{z}}{z^2-1}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, residue-calculus

> Evaluate  $\oint_C \frac{e^\frac{1}{z}}{z^2-1} dz$ where $C$ is the locus of $z$ satisfying $|z-1|<3/2$ (answer: $iπ/e$).

My attempt at an answer comes nowhere close to this given result:

The two residues inside our contour are at $z=0$ and $z=1$.
By Cauchy's residue theorem, the value of the integral is $2\pi i$ times the sum of these two residues.

At $z=ε, ε\ll 1$, we have:
$$\frac{1}{ε^2-1}(1+1/ε+...) \rightarrow \frac{1}{-1}(1+1/ε+...) \rightarrow \text{Res} = -1$$

At $z=1+ε$, we have:
$$ e^\frac{1}{1+ε} \frac{1}{(ε)(2+ε)} \rightarrow \frac{1}{ε} e/2  \rightarrow \text{Res} = e/2$$

So my answer is $2πi (\frac{e}{2}-1)$ - apparently this is completely wrong though! The only way I can see to get the given answer is if we include the resiude at $z=-1$. Have I completely misunderstood something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is from here

> At $z=ε, ε\ll 1$, we have:
> $$\frac{1}{ε^2-1}(1+1/ε+...) \rightarrow \frac{1}{-1}(1+1/ε+...) \rightarrow \text{Res} = -1$$

At $z=0$, do the Laurent series:

$$\frac1{z^2-1}e^{1/z}=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{k!}z^{-k}\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2n} $$

take the coefficient for the $z^{-1}$ term,

$$\text{Res}(z=0)=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(2k+1)!}=-\sinh1=\frac{1}{2e}-\frac e2$$

So we get

$$\text{Res}(z=0)+\text{Res}(z=1)=\frac{1}{2e}-\frac e2+\frac e2=\frac{1}{2e}$$

which matches the answer.

---

**Best Method** is to consider the area enclosed by the contour outside $|z-1|\ge \frac32$, which includes a simple pole at $z=-1$ and the singuarity $z=\infty$. Note that $z=\infty$ is analytic in your case. So the residue at $z=\infty$ is zero. And you immediately get the answer by only computing the residue at $z=-1$. But be careful to add an additional $-$ sign in this case because the contour is clockwise with respect to the area outside $|z-1|\ge \frac32$.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the computation of the residue of the integrand at $z = 0$, i.e., in this computation:

> At $z=ε, ε\ll 1$, we have:
> $$\frac{1}{ε^2-1}(1+1/ε+...) \rightarrow \frac{1}{-1}(1+1/ε+...) \rightarrow \text{Res} = -1$$

Denote $$f(z) := \frac{\exp \frac1z}{z^2 - 1} .$$

**Hint** When $|z| < 1$, $$\frac{1}{z^2 - 1} = -(1 + z^2 + z^4 + \cdots),$$
so the Laurent expansion of $\frac{\exp \frac1z}{z^2 - 1}$ in $\{0 < |z| < 1\}$ is given by expanding
the product
$$-(1 + z^2 + z^4 + \cdots) \left(1 + \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2z^2} + \frac{1}{3!z^3} + \cdots\right) .$$
In particular, the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ is
$$\operatorname{Res}\left(f, 0\right) = -\left(1 + \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{5!} + \cdots\right) .$$

> **Additional hint** We recognize the quantity in parentheses as the Taylor expansion of $\sinh z = \frac{1}{2}(\exp z - \exp(-z))$ evaluated at $z = 1$, so the residue at $0$ is $$\operatorname{Res}\left(f, 0\right) = -\sinh 1 = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{e}-e\right) .$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the other answers, another way would be the change of variables $\zeta = \frac{1}{z}$, i.e. $d z = -\frac{1}{\zeta^2}d\zeta$.

The only thing one has to be careful with is the contour one integrates over: Denote by $\Gamma$ the circle described by $|z-1|=\frac{3}{2}$, then the conformal change of coordinates above maps $\Gamma$ again to a circle $\Gamma'$. As one easily verifies, $\Gamma$ encircled $z=1$ once in anti-clockwise direction and did not encircle $z=-1$, while in the image coordinates, $\Gamma'$ encircles $\zeta = -1$ in the clockwise direction, but not $\zeta=1$.

Thus, one has:

\begin{align}\int\limits_\Gamma \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z^2-1}dz &= -\int\limits_{\Gamma'} \frac{e^\zeta}{\frac{1}{\zeta^2}-1}\frac{1}{\zeta^2}d \zeta\\
& = \int\limits_{\Gamma'} \frac{e^\zeta}{\zeta^2-1}d\zeta\\
& =  w(\Gamma',-1)\cdot 2\pi i \cdot \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{e^\zeta}{\zeta^2-1},  -1\right)\\
& = -2\pi i\cdot \frac{e^{-1}}{-2}\\
& = \frac{\pi i}{e}
\end{align}
In the third line, $w(\Gamma',-1)=-1$ denotes the winding number of $\Gamma'$ around $-1$ (it is negative because $\Gamma'$ is going in the clockwise direction).

Comment: I wrote this method in the last paragraph of my answer.